# How does the Grails fields plugin work when creating a simple insert form?

Tags: grails, grails-plugin, grails-3.1

App info:

- Grails Version: 3.1.8
- Groovy Version: 2.4.6
- Java: 8

I have added in the fields plugin as a dependency in build.gradle and I'm using fields version 2.1.0. The documentation available for this is [here](http://grails3-plugins.github.io/fields/snapshot/guide/index.html).

My domain class is as follows:

```
    String name
    String addressLine1
    String addressLine2
    String addressLine3
    String town
    String county
    String postCode
    String phoneNumber
```

I want to create a simple insert form for this object. My form currently:

```
<g:form name="insertPerson" controller="person" action="savePerson">

    <f:field bean="person" property="name"/>

    <g:submitButton name="create"/>

</g:form>
```

I understand the fields plugin has fields and widget templates which I have created the necessary folders and gsp files. What is meant to go in these files to make my form work?

Answer (score 1):

You should not need anything other than your domain and the

```
<f:all bean="person" />
```

That will render all the fields in the bean.
If you want to override only then start looking at making templates.
You can see what the plugin fields plugin generates by looking in [Github](https://github.com/grails3-plugins/fields/blob/master/grails-app/views/templates/_fields/_list.gsp)

(Or you can look directly at the generated html source)

The f:all, f:field is really more for scaffolding. If you want complete control use
[g:field](http://docs.grails.org/2.1.0/ref/Tags/field.html)
And related tags

Comment: I'm using Fields version 2.1.0 which is a fork from 1.4 and this does not support the f:all tag. I have deleted the templating folders which I had created however the form still doesn't work as I'm getting the error below. ERROR errors.GrailsExceptionResolver  - NotReadablePropertyException 
Invalid property 'name' of bean class [java.lang.String]: Bean property 'name' is not readable or has an invalid getter method: Does the return type of the getter match the parameter type of the setter?.